# Owasp ZAP tool - how to get list of passed tests

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I used OWASP ZAP to scan an application I developed. The scan report lists out vulnerabilities, if any. If not, nothing gets printed. Does ZAP provide a list of tests that passed? How to obtain such a report?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to get all the scan rules (`<zap_host>/JSON/pscan/view/scanners/?zapapiformat=JSON&formMethod=GET` 
 or `<zap_host>/JSON/ascan/view/scanners/?zapapiformat=JSON&formMethod=GET&scanPolicyName=&policyId=`), which is similar to all the tests. Another option is to get all URLs scanned by Zap (`<zap_host>/JSON/core/view/urls/?zapapiformat=JSON&formMethod=GET&baseurl=`). Hope that helps...

Comment: could you add some more information about using the API, or what <zap_host> is referring to.

Comment: Sure, you can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiDetails). The <zap_host> is the URL of the machine running Zap, including the port (the one used for proxying)